# How to toggle class on and off depending if input field value

Tags: javascript

If the input contains a whitespace, add classList 'invalid', otherwise remove it.

```
function idValidationAttacher() {
    const id = document.querySelector('#newid');


    id.addEventListener('input', id.classList.toggle('invalid', ));
}
```

Comment: An event listener must be a function.

Comment: You might want to simply use the `pattern` attribute of the input.

Comment: is it possible without regex

Comment: Yes you can do it without regex as well.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const id = document.getElementById('newid');


id.addEventListener("input", () => {
  if(id.value.includes(" ")) {
    // Add the code to show the error here.
  }
});
```